# Проблема с переменными в php при ajax-запросе

Tags: веб-программирование, ajax, php

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с следующей проблемой. Кусок кода из php:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM security WHERE id = '".$id."'");
        while( $row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            $array[] = $row;
        if($array[0]['class'] == 'btn btn-xs btn-success'){
            $array[0]['class'] = 'btn btn-xs btn-warning';
            $array[0]['value'] = $array[0]['value_off'];
            echo $array[0]['value'];
        }
```

Кусок кода из js обработчика:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: './AjaxCore.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:params,
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(){ 
            $('#'+this.id+'').attr('class', this.class);
            $('#'+this.id+'').text(this.value);
    });
},
    error: function(){
        alert('oops');
    }
});
```

При прямом ***GET*** запросе все получается, но через ***ajax***

```
            $array[0]['value'] = $array[0]['value_off'];
```

не присваивается. В чем тут дело?

Comment: Слишком много ошибок. А какую ошибку пишет?)

Comment: В том и дело, что ошибку поймать не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотели отправить ajax-запрос в файл, находящийся в директории выше, то в параметре 
**url** нужно поставить ещё одну точку.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `$array[0]['class']` не равен `'btn btn-xs btn-success'`, очевидно.

Comment: Нет, он равен. Присвоение    `$array[0]['class'] = 'btn btn-xs btn-warning';`    проходит

Comment: Тогда в `$array[0]['value_off']` что-то не то. Присвоение никак не зависит от типа запроса.

Comment: Я знаю, что не зависит. Поэтому и не понятно мне, почему у меня зависит. Вот полностью обработчик php и ajax http://jsfiddle.net/OlegFM/61maehgr/

Answer (score 0):

Каким образом Вы инициализируете переменную **$id**?

Если следующим образом:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

то убедитесь, что ваш AJAX запрос отправляется методом *GET*.

В `jQuery` этот метод используется по умолчанию, 
для большей уверенности можно определить метод вручную:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "",
  type: "GET",
});
```

Comment: AJAX передается в GET. Не проходит именно:     $array[0]['value'] = $array[0]['value_off'];